# 'Connection Refused' Error when running a home-made RESTful (Java) Web Service's Client App

Tags: rest

**The Error printout is...**

```
C:\DEV\RESTful WS Projects\Predictions_Client>java predictions3/client/PredictionsJersey2Client
Exception in thread "main" javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:287)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:252)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$2.call(JerseyInvocation.java:701)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:444)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:697)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:420)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.get(JerseyInvocation.java:316)
        at predictions3.client.PredictionsJersey2Client.getXmlPrediction(PredictionsJersey2Client.java:28)
        at predictions3.client.PredictionsJersey2Client.main(PredictionsJersey2Client.java:20)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1169)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1105)
```

my source code is...

```
package predictions3.client;

import org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyClient;
import org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import predictions3.Prediction;


public class PredictionsJersey2Client {

   private static final String REST_URI = 
                  "http://localhost:8080/predictions3/resourcesP/";

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       PredictionsJersey2Client donut = new PredictionsJersey2Client();
      Prediction pred = donut.getXmlPrediction(2); 
      System.out.print("wxyz");
   }

   public Prediction getXmlPrediction(int id) {
      //  create a new Client instance using a new ClientConfig instance 
      //  JerseyClient client = JerseyClientBuilder.createClient( new ClientConfig().register( LoggingFilter.class ) );
      JerseyClient client = JerseyClientBuilder.createClient();
      return client.target(REST_URI).path(String.valueOf(id)).request(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).get(Prediction.class);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please disregard my question.  I forgot to startup my Tomcat7 localhost.  Now that it is up-and-running I am getting a more manageable 404 error .  Sorry for any inconvenience.  I'm glad I joined the Group, though.